# How can I complete this proof?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have finished all but the last line. Thanks in advance for any help.

**Proof statement:** If $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y \rightarrow Z$ are both differentiable, then $h=g \circ f$ is differentiable, and its derivative is given by the chain rule $Dh(x)=Dg(f(x))Df(x).$

**Incomplete proof:** By the differentiability of $f$, we have $$f(x+a)=f(x)+Df(x)a+w(a)$$ where $\frac{\|w(a)\|}{\|a\|} \rightarrow 0$ as $\|a\| \rightarrow 0$. We need to show that $Dh(x)=Dg(f(x))Df(x)$ where $h=g \circ f$. Let $z=f(x)$ and $j=Df(x)a + w(a)$. Then $g(z+j) = g(z) + Dg(z)j + l(j)$, where $\frac{\|l(j)\|}{\|j\|} \rightarrow 0$ as $\|j\| \rightarrow 0$. Hence $$g(f(x+a))=g[f(x)+Df(x)a+w(a)]=g(z+j)=g(z)+Dg(z)[Df(x)a+w(a)]+l(j)=g(z)+Dg(z)Df(x)a+p(a)$$ where $p(a)=Dg(z)w(a)+l(j)=Dg(f(x))w(a)+l[Df(x)a+w(a)].$ Since $Df(x), Dg(z)$ are bounded linear maps, we have

$$\frac{\|p(a)\|}{\|a\|}=\frac{\|Dg(f(x))w(a)+l(j)\|}{\|a\|} \leq \frac{\|Dg(z)w(a)\|}{\|a\|}+\frac{\|l(j)\|}{\|a\|} \leq \frac{\|Dg(f(x))w(a)\|}{\|a\|} + \frac{\|l(j)\|}{\|j\|}\frac{\|j\|}{\|a\|}$$

Since $\frac{\|w(a)\|}{\|a\|}$ and$\frac{\|l(j)\|}{\|j\|}$ approach $0$ as $a \rightarrow 0$ we have that $\frac{\|p(a)\|}{\|a\|}$ approaches $0$ as $a \rightarrow 0$.

How do I conclude with proper notation?

Comment: I haven’t looked through all of this, but let me upvote this for effort nonetheless. Seems legit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every bounded linear map goes to 0 as the norm of its argument goes to 0. For a bounded linear map $T: V \to W$,
$$\|Tv\| \leq | T|\|v\|$$
where $|T| = \sup\{\frac{\|Tv\|}{\|v\|} \mid v \in V \setminus \{0\}\}$ exists since the operator is bounded.

Comment: How do I connect this to the original statement of the chain rule?

Comment: Use this at the very end to complete the proof: it shows $\frac{\|Dg(f(x))w(a)\|}{\|a\|}$ goes to 0.